# How can I create an alias to a directory so that I don't have to type the long path every time?

Tags: bash

Currently, to get to the directory I need to type this:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/FolderBelongingToUser
```

Is there a way to make it so that I can just type something like:

```
cd FolderBelongingToUser ?
```

Comment: Is this alias in vim or in bash? I have a feeling the answer is `cd ~/FolderBelongingToUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using OSX you can open the hidden file named `.bash_profile` in your root user directory and add an entry like this:

```
alias define_your_shortcut='define your path'
```

You can do this for anything.  For example here is an alias for your example:

```
alias FolderBelongingToUser='cd /cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/FolderBelongingToUser'
```

Here's another example using a command to toggle hidden files

```
alias showfiles='defaults write com.apple.finder ShowAllFiles TRUE'
alias hidefiles='defaults write com.apple.finder ShowAllFiles FALSE'
```

After you make any changes to your bash_profile you'll need to either logout and login or you can open terminal and tell it to reload your bash_profile with this command

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

---

I'm not personally familiar with Windows but if your using Windows a quick search result explained that this is how you would create a command prompt alias in Windows

```
AddConsoleAlias( TEXT("test"), 
             TEXT("cd \\<a_very_long_path>\\test"), 
             TEXT("cmd.exe"));
```

Alternatively it looks like someone provided a good answer to doing this in Windows here:  https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with [z](https://github.com/rupa/z) (uses ranking) and [cdargs](http://www.skamphausen.de/cgi-bin/ska/CDargs) (uses shortcuts) but there are many other tools designed to make navigation in your shell easier *and* built-in solutions like `CDPATH` or the `**` wildcard…

- `CDPATH`

  Adding something like this in your `*rc` file:

  ```
  export CDPATH='.:~:/cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/'
  ```

  allows you to do exactly what you are after:

  ```
  $ cd FolderBelongingToUser
  ```

  or, better:

  ```
  $ cd Fold<Tab>
  ```
- `**`

  If your bash is recent enough, you can do something like this:

  $ cd **/foo

Answer (score 0):

Vim normally supports tab completion, so you can probably type something like

> cd ~Nam<kbd>Tab</kbd>Fol<kbd>Tab</kbd>

which will expand to

> cd /cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/FolderBelongingToUser

Of course, if NameOfUser is you, then you can probably just type

> cd ~/Fol<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me, but I just discovered that I can type `alias shortcut='cd'\''/cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/Folder'\'''` and that creates the keyword to jump to that folder.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking about within Vim. I see now that you are actually asking for a shell alias, which you found.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I'm very new to unix and all of the jargon, and I guess I just didn't know how to phrase my question correctly. Thanks anyway for your input

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line to your .vimrc

```
cabbr FolderBelongingToUser /cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/FolderBelongingToUser
```

Then you can can

```
cd FolderBelongingToUser
```

If you want to add more to the path (eg to specify a filename with `:w`) you can press <kbd>/</kbd> after `FolderBelongingToUser` and it will replace it with the full path and allow you to continue typing.

**:ca[bbrev]** is a Command line only abbreviation. See: `:help :cabbr`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a permanent alias, then in your `~/.bashrc`, create an alias:

```
alias FTBU='/cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/FolderBelongingToUser'
```

You will then be able to access it in your shell by:

```
$ cd FTBU
```

As another trick, if you are only going to use the `alias` to change to the directory then simply add `cd` to the `alias`

```
alias FTBU='cd /cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/FolderBelongingToUser'
```

You then need only type:

```
$ FTBU
```

to change to the `/cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/FolderBelongingToUser` directory. However, if you plan to use the `alias` for any other purpose, leave the `cd` out of the `alias` definition.

If this is a temporary alias, you can simply create an alias from the command line with:

```
$ alias FTBU='/cygdrive/c/Users/NameOfUser/FolderBelongingToUser'
```

with the same results. (substitute anything you like for `FTBU`) **Note:** you remove an `alias` with the `unalias` command. **Also Note:** you should to check whether an existing system command exists with the name of your alias before assigning it. Simply type the proposed `alias` at the command line. If you receive something line `bash: your_alias: Command Not Found`, then you are good to go. There is no minimum number of characters required in an `alias`. So it you want to use a single-character, that's fine.